# Windbg and viewing AppDomain content

Tags: c#, windbg, appdomain, linqpad

I know we can use !dumpdomain command in winbbg to view the various app domains present in a given managed process(e.g. w3wp).

I wrote a small program(Recipe 3-1 from Visual C# 2010 Recipes A problem solution approach) in LinqPad, to create a custom AppDomain. This is where I am facing issues. I am not able to view this appdomain using windbg. In other words, where is this app domain created ? Is it hosted inside LinqPad process ? If not, then which process is hosting this custom appdomain ?

I tried  attaching LinqPad.exe to windbg and issues !dumpdomain command but I got the following error :

> Failed to find runtime DLL (clr.dll), 0x80004005 Extension commands
>   need clr.dll in order to have something to do.

Code :

```
void Main()
{
    AppDomainSetup setUpInfo = new AppDomainSetup();

    setUpInfo.ApplicationBase = @"C:\MyRootDirectory";
    setUpInfo.ConfigurationFile = "MyApp.config";
    setUpInfo.PrivateBinPath = "bin;plugins;external";

    AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("My New Domain",null,setUpInfo);

    Console.WriteLine("Main method complete.Press Enter");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Steps Followed :

- Run the program. It waits for the user to press Enter.
- Start windbg. Attach LinqPad.exe.
- issue commands : .load sos.dll and .load sosex.dll
- Issue command .reload
- Finally call !dumpdomain. At this point the LinqPad freezes. If I close the windbg, then LinqPad is also closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's created inside the LINQPad process. Your query itself runs in separate AppDomain created by LINQPad. Could the error message be related to a CLR version mismatch? Are you running LINQPad 2.x or 4.x?

Comment: I am using v4.31 of LinqPad. The loaded SOS.dll is corresponding to .Net 4.0 version. I have updated the question with the code, that I am using to create the app domain.